# How to retain same URL after moving subsite from one farm to another

Tags: url

We've two subsites (IN and US) in one farm. We're planning to move one subsite (US) to another SPFarm.

```
  `Before moving: http://mysite1/IN/ and http://mysite1/US/`
  `After moving US: http://mysite1/US/`
```

Note: we're using SP2013.

But we want to retain the same URL `(http://mysite1/US/)`?

Please suggest some solution. Is it something to do with IIS url redirect? If yes, Please let me know how ?

To make it clear

**FARM One**

`http://mysite1.com` is the top-level site.

`http://mysite1.com/IN` is one subsite
`http://mysite1.com/US` is another subsite

We're planning to move US subsite of FARM one to FARM two

**FARM two (After moving)**

`http://mysite1.com/US`

FYI: 'mysite1' is not the server name. It is just an alias name given in DNS.

Is it possible to have the same domain name and URL after moving?

I'm not combining two subsites and yes, Intranet.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to combine the two subsites into one? I'm I correct?

Comment: more information required....both are subsites or two seprate site collections? you want move US to new farm and want retain the same URL? sites are on intranet or public network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same domain in two farms unless you have some sort of traffic manager that determine which farm should respond to which traffic.

mysite1 - IP 1
mysite1 - IP 2

If you load this in DNS you get a round robin issue, and if the farms are not identical you will start hitting 403's and site not found issues. Instead you may want to look at using a new domain say mysite2 in the new farm.  Then in the original use IIS Re-Write module to create a rule so that when you come in with mysite1/us you are sent to mysite2/us.

You can also do this by creating a redirect page directly on the mystie1/us home page, but I prefer the re-write module for maintainability and it is easy in the future to extend it to include other sites.